# Splitting multipart polygon into singlepart polygons using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, multipart, singlepart

How do I split a multipart polygon which consists of several polygons into singlepart polygons so I can delete each polygon without deleting them all at one time?

I am using ArcMap 10.0.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Under "Advanced Editing" there is a Button for "Explode Multi-Part features". Worked just fine!

Answer (score 19):

You can use the [Multipart To Singlepart (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003r000000) tool which:

> Creates a feature class containing singlepart features generated by separating multipart input features.

Answer (score 3):

ArcMap, arctoolbox -> data management -> features -> Multipart to singlepart

Qgis, vector menu -> Geometry tools -> Multipart To Singlepart.

arcmap, No advance license need,