# Getting new start and end points (X & Y) for new clipped line sections using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I'm trying to get start and end points, and lengths for clipped sections of lines (roads) that fall in my polygon. Each road has two to three different sections within the polygon. I clipped the roads with the polygon, to show me only sections of the roads that go through the polygon.

Now I am trying to break up each section into its own line segment.

Then I am trying to get the start and end points (X&Y coordinates), and length of each segmented line.

I tried linear referencing, but has not work, might be doing it wrong. Also each road has a start point and a end point, but those are for the entire road, these points are not within my clipped area.

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What is your question?  Using a single question mark somewhere in your question body is the way to make that clear.

Comment: You always need to update X and Y and other fields when you have changed the shape. In your attribute table, right click on the appropriate field/column and select Calculate Geometry. Try reading the help on this tool and testing the tool, then edit your post with more specific questions.

Comment: Use multipart to single part and add geometry attributes to resulting segments.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107850/splitting-multi-part-polygon-into-single-polygons-using-arcgis-desktop https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113569/uses-for-calculate-geometry-option https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88092/calculating-x-and-y-of-line-start-and-line-end-using-arcpy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting multi-part polygon into single polygons using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107850/splitting-multi-part-polygon-into-single-polygons-using-arcgis-desktop)